# How to resolve Studio's "unavailable color" warning for EV3 motors and sensors?

Tags: ev3, piece-information, ldd, colour, bricklink-studio

I have recently switched to Studio from Lego Digital Designer for designing EV3 robots and other mechanisms. It's a great program, but the color palette is driving me crazy.

I want to add Lego EV3 motors and sensors (e.g. the [99455 medium motor](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=99455)) to my model, but when I do, a persistent "unavailable color" issue appears in the step list.

[image: Screenshot]

I have tried resolving this by changing the color to White, Very Light Bluish Gray, Very Light Gray, Light Bluish Gray, and Light Gray. None of them make the warning go away. It's driving me nuts.

I don't understand why this happens. The motors only have one design: white and gray. In cases like this (where only one color scheme exists), I should only be allowed to pull the part out of the palette in its default color.

Further, I don't see a way to learn how to fix it. Studio doesn't show me what colors *are* available for this part, at least as far as I can see.

Can anyone help? First, what is the correct color for EV3 parts to avoid this warning? Second, is there a way in Studio to learn this answer, in case I run into similar situations?

Comment: I don't use Studio, so may be wrong. As far as I know Studio use element information and colors from Bricklink. Your particular motor (see URL I've included in your question) is listed as "Not applicable" color, which might explain why have the error and none of the colors fit.

Comment: In the latest version 2.2.8(1) of Studio, if I select 99455 from the Master parts palette it is in white and tan. I can change the tan color to anything I want with the right hand panels. I don't know why they error is "driving you nuts" - it doesn't stop anything working, so just ignore it. (Note, I have no idea what is the real color of an EV3 brick.)

Comment: Those yellow exclamation marks are like social media notifications that I can't make go away. As I work, my brain keeps thinking "you have to fix those."  I _want_ my attention drawn to legitimate problems that need fixing ... but these are not fixable.

Comment: @Kirkman14 Well, right now I have more than 3500 unread messages in my SE inbox, and I don't plan to read any of them soon. I guess my attitude to "social media messages" is different form yours! IMO the entire error-reporting interface in Studio should be redesigned if it is going to be useful.

Answer (score 3):

According to SylvainLS in [this BrickLink post](https://forum.bricklink.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6909&sid=9b0ac4713ef377a2f2ba4544e88e0682), these are the answers to my questions:

- You can find out which colors are available for a part by selecting a part, opening the Color Palette on the right side of the interface, and selecting the `Hide unavailable colors` option.
- In  the BrickLink catalog, [part 99455](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=99455#T=C&C=0) and many other EV3-specific pieces are set to a special `Not Applicable` color category. Studio doesn't have this N/A color category, so it thinks the part is not available in any color. Hence the warnings.